# Go multilevel data structure

Tags: xml, go

Deal all,

I want to return multilevel data json to user. something like this

```
{ "screen"[{ 
           "screen_id":"001",
           "screen_name":"screen_001"
            "key": [ {
                    "id":"key_001",
                    "name":"key_001"                                   
                    },    
                     {
                    "id":"key_002",
                    "name":"key_002"                                   
                    },   
                   ] 
           }, 
           "screen_id":"002",
           "screen_name":"screen_002"
            "key": [ {
                    "id":"key_002",
                    "name":"key_002"                                   
                    },    
                     {
                    "id":"key_003",
                    "name":"key_003"                                   
                    },   
                   ] 
       }
```

I guess using XML will be more suitable way to represent the data structure, because the screen item and key subitem will be inserted dynamically. Am I correct, or there exist other better way? If using XML, can u shed some light on it?

Thanks

Comment: JSON and XML are both basically the same in this application. It's really up to you and the client.

Answer (score 1):

The code below does what you want. The key is to separate the JSON message blocks into logical structs, and then group them together to make the message. See http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go and http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/ for more info.

To convert the object to JSON, use the [`json.Marshal function`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal).

To convert the object to XML, use the [`xml.Marshal function`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal).

The code below uses the `MarshalIndent` functions to pretty-print the output.

```go
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Key struct {
    Id   string `json:"id" xml:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name" xml:"name"`
}

type Screen struct {
    ScreenId   string `json:"screen_id" xml:"screen_id"`
    ScreenName string `json:"screen_name" xml:"screen_name"`
    Keys       []Key  `json:"key" xml:"key"`
}

type Message struct {
    Screens []Screen `json:"screen" xml:"screen"`
}

func main() {

    msg := Message{
        []Screen{
            Screen{
                "001",
                "screen_001",
                []Key{
                    Key{
                        "key_001",
                        "key_001",
                    },
                    Key{
                        "key_002",
                        "key_002",
                    },
                },
            },
            Screen{
                "002",
                "screen_002",
                []Key{
                    Key{
                        "key_002",
                        "key_002",
                    },
                    Key{
                        "key_003",
                        "key_003",
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }

    jsonMsg, err := json.MarshalIndent(msg, "", "\t")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", jsonMsg)

    xmlMsg, err := xml.MarshalIndent(msg, "", "\t")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", xmlMsg)
}
```

Will produce:

```
{
        "screen": [
                {
                        "screen_id": "001",
                        "screen_name": "screen_001",
                        "key": [
                                {
                                        "id": "key_001",
                                        "name": "key_001"
                                },
                                {
                                        "id": "key_002",
                                        "name": "key_002"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "screen_id": "002",
                        "screen_name": "screen_002",
                        "key": [
                                {
                                        "id": "key_002",
                                        "name": "key_002"
                                },
                                {
                                        "id": "key_003",
                                        "name": "key_003"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
<Message>
        <screen>
                <screen_id>001</screen_id>
                <screen_name>screen_001</screen_name>
                <key>
                        <id>key_001</id>
                        <name>key_001</name>
                </key>
                <key>
                        <id>key_002</id>
                        <name>key_002</name>
                </key>
        </screen>
        <screen>
                <screen_id>002</screen_id>
                <screen_name>screen_002</screen_name>
                <key>
                        <id>key_002</id>
                        <name>key_002</name>
                </key>
                <key>
                        <id>key_003</id>
                        <name>key_003</name>
                </key>
        </screen>
</Message>
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/P-NcNh63yI)